# Yahoo Finance API Error

Tags: yahoo-api

I was just wondering if this code is the right API for yahoo finance because it does not work. If someone has the right API I would love to hear a response.

Here is the code.

```
let urlString:String = ("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * 
from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol IN 
"+stringQuotes+"&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env").stringByAdd
ingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

Answer (score 1):

there is an issue at the moment with http://datatables.org/
seems the website is not responding which makes all the yql queries for Community Data tables not to work.

Seems it has been down for about 12 hours. I hope they don't shut it down :(

Your url is missing the brackets surronding stringQuotes (just thought of mentioning in case your string variable "stringQuotes" does not have it)

```
let urlString:String = ("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * 
from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol IN 
("+stringQuotes+")&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env").stringByAdd
ingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

Comment: Other than that, should this code still work. @Dilberted

Comment: yup. it is fine. there are no issues.